# Flask migrate fails with extension not loaded

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate

Initialization code
extensions.py

```py
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

from authentek.logger import log

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
cors = CORS(resources={r"/v1/*": {"origins": "*"}})
log.debug("in debug mode")
```

```py
from authentek.extensions import db, migrate, bcrypt, cors

def configure_extensions(flask_app, cli):
    """configure flask extensions
    """
    db.init_app(flask_app)

    blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/v1')
    api.init_app(blueprint)
    api.add_namespace(users_namespace)
    api.add_namespace(auth_namespace)
    if blueprint.name not in flask_app.blueprints.keys():
        flask_app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
    else:
        flask_app.blueprints[blueprint.name] = blueprint

    cors.init_app(flask_app)
    db.app = flask_app
    db.create_all()

    bcrypt.init_app(flask_app)
    if cli is True:
        migrate.init_app(flask_app, db) # here it's registered
```

```py
flask db migrate
2020-06-27 09:09:04,827 - authentek.logger - DEBUG - in debug mode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 426, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_migrate/cli.py", line 88, in migrate
    rev_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 175, in migrate
    config = current_app.extensions['migrate'].migrate.get_config(
KeyError: 'migrate'
```

repository: https://github.com/eshta/authentek

Comment: Just getting the obvious answers out of the way. You're sure `cli` is True? Did you try debugging `configure_extensions`?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized the `migrate` instance.

```
def configure_extensions(flask_app, cli):
    """configure flask extensions
    """
    db.init_app(flask_app)
    migrate.init_app(flask_app, db)

    # ...
```

Also, remove `db.create_all()`, since you want Flask-Migrate to manage your database schema.